# Cannot run ubuntu emulator on ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-emulator

I installed ubuntu emulator through ubuntu SDK.
When i do `ubuntu-emulator list`
i get my emulator name but when i do
  `ubuntu-emulator run deviceone` 
it says  `open /home/amarendra/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/deviceone/.device: no such file or directory`
I have seen the content there is just one sdcard.img file at the error location.

How can i resolved this ? New to  ubuntu development.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was also reported on Launchpad and forums:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/goget-ubuntu-touch/+bug/1331177

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208424

There are two suggestions currently but neither one worked for me:

- installing libudev1:i386
- using --use-raw-disk key

I've recreated the emulator image and this `.device` file contains only one line:

```
i386
```

Comment: it say that "Cannot run specified emulator environment"