# Ubuntu emulator takes +100% CPU but doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, arm, ubuntu-emulator

I've checked the emulator docs on ubuntu devel web and here on askubuntu, but
can't find anything addressing this emulator problem, so I'm posting it
here.

When installing emulator from Android SDK and trying to run, the armhf
just hangs even after 12 minutes. The i386 comes up after a couple of
minutes. But both of them are using 100% + of my CPU, with the fan going
nuts. I've attached the output from starting the emulators from command
line.

---

Trying to add a device kit for the emulators generates error "the
supported framework is not known," although
the emulator setup docs don't describe any additional steps to be made
other than the normal menu setup.

See screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmijU.jpg

---

Also, trying to make an emulator from command line ends in this:

> lash@CANTANDO ~ $ sudo ubuntu-emulator create testemu3 --arch=armhf
>   --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
>
> Creating "testemu3" from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en revision 14
>
> Downloading...
>
> 31.62 MB / 31.62 MB [====================================] 100.00 %
>   669.31 KB/s
>
> 282.00 MB / 282.00 MB [====================================] 100.00 %
>   1.20 MB/s
>
> Setting up...
>
> Setting up a default password for phablet to: ''
>
> No password supplied
>
> No password supplied
>
> No password supplied
>
> chpasswd: (user phablet) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
>
> Authentication token manipulation error
>
> chpasswd: (line 1, user phablet) password not changed
>
> lash@CANTANDO ~ $ ubuntu-emulator run testemu3
>   open /home/lash/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/testemu3/.device: no such
>   file or directory

This problem is mentioned here: [Cannot run ubuntu emulator on ubuntu12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486291/cannot-run-ubuntu-emulator-on-ubuntu12-04) but as I'm able to MAKE an emulator through the SDK, it's probably not really critical.

---

The logs for the run attempts can be viewed here:

https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg12901.html

Answer (score 2):

Supply password also while creating emulator

```
sudo ubuntu-emulator create ubuntuTouch --arch=i386 --password=0000
```

[image]